# how to update data in bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have one bootstrap table with following code.

```
  <table id="tblPendingRequests" data-height="300">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th data-field="Version">Version</th>
             <th data-field="Env">Env</th>
             <th data-field="Release">Release</th>
             <th data-field="CreatedBy">Created By</th>
             <th data-field="Action">Action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
```

added below references also.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and my jquery code to load data

```
     function loadData()
     {
       $(function () {
        $('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable({
        });
      });
     }
```

and then I am loading some data to this table. Like this:

```
var mydata = { "Version": data[index].DeploymentName, "Env": data[index].EnvName, 
                  "Release":data[index].ReleaseName, "CreatedBy": data[index].UpdatedBy  "Action": ActionButton };
            testData.push(mydata);
      updateData(testData);
  function updateData(myData) {
     $('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable("append", myData);

      }
```

It is diplaying the data properly. I have one project dropdown on the page. Onchange of the project name i want to populate this table with fresh data. It is not happening. It is appending data to existing table data which i don't want.

How to refresh the table and load new data in the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the `load` instead of `append`.

From the [official documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/)

> **[append](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#append)** - Append the data to table.
>
> **[load](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#load)** - Load the data to table, the old rows will be removed.

Also both functions accept the same argument `data`.

Comment: but load function will work only on page load. If after page load i try to load the table with new data it is not working.

Comment: @user1826456 Here the `load` is not an event, which we are listening to. It is simply the method name, which we are calling. So there is no reason why it will work on page load only. Here is an example of all `table actions` in the official documentation, which also includes the `load` method: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#table-methods Check out, please.

Comment: Here's the updated link: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#m

Answer (score 10):

I destroy the table, `$('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable("destroy");` and then reload the data, `$('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable({data: myFreshData});`.

From a performance perspective it might not be as fast as getting `load` to work, but it's fast enough that I've never noticed a switch over with up to 1,000 rows.

**Update 10.4.2018**
Came back to bootstrap table this past month and `load` is working for me as advertised now, so I'm no longer suggesting this workaround.